# How to Upload a Google Apps Script via the Google Drive API (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to use the [Google API NodeJS client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to upload a Google Apps Script to my drive. I am following the directions in the docs, but when the file gets uploaded to my drive, I can only upload it as plain text and not as an Apps Script.

```
function uploadAppScript(auth) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var drive = google.drive('v3')
  drive.files.create({
    auth: auth,
    resource: {
      name: 'myscript',
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.script'
    },
    media: {
      mimeType: 'text/plain',
      body: fs.createReadStream('src/myscript.gs') 
    },
  }, function(err, result){
       ... //not relevant
  })
})
```

}

The [media uploads](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#media-uploads) section of the README does not specify how to upload anything other than a png.

If I change the `mimeType` in the `media` object to anything other than `text/plain` I get the following (uninformative) error:

```
code: 400,
  errors: 
    [ { domain: 'global',
        reason: 'badRequest',
        message: 'Bad Request' } ] }
```

Any ideas on how to get Drive to recognize this as an Apps Script and not a plain text file? Or is this something broken on the NodeJS client's end?

Comment: Have a look at the `sendToGoogle` function in *node-google-apps-script*, in the [`upload.js`](https://github.com/danthareja/node-google-apps-script/blob/master/lib/commands/upload.js) file. It uses Drive v2, but should give some options.

Comment: @Bardy tried a bunch of combinations of MIME types based on that file but still got the same 400 error code. I think I might need to upload it as a google-doc and then convert it to a google-app-script. I'm gonna try that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is apparently a bug with the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) but a maintainer of the library was able to assist me where the documentation could not. The following will allow you to upload a `.gs` file to Google Drive properly:

```
drive.files.create({
  resource: {
    name: 'myscript.gs',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.script+json'
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.script+json',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      files: [
        {
          source: fs.readFileSync('src/myscript.gs', { encoding: 'utf-8' }),
          name: 'myscript',
          type: 'server_js'
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}, function (err, file) {
  // ...
});
```